# TR 2990X & AsRock X399 TAICHI, RAM not recognized properly

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, threadripper

I have the following system configuration:

- CPU: AMD Threadripper 2990WX
- RAM: 4x8GB + 4x16GB G.Skill Trident Z DDR4-3200 (running at 2933)
- Mainboard: Asrock x399 Taichi
- SSD: Samsung 970 Evo 500 GB
- Custom water cooling

Problem:

RAM slots A1 and A2 are not recognized as soon as I mount the cooler. SSD is never recognized, but was running fine before.

What I have tried so far:

- Running single RAM sticks in A1 or A2, resulting in error 16 (RAM failing) or F9 (CPU wrongly mounted)
- Running all RAM sticks (A1 and A2 not recognized)
- removing the SSD, no change.
- checking the CPU pins, seem ok
- varied the pressure of the CPU cooler to see if anything changes -> nothing
- vacuumed the socket (not touching) to remove dust
- resocketed the CPU multiple times (sometimes RAM is there, sometimes not. After putting the cooler on, its never detected in A1/2).

What else can I try? I'm running out of options here.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here. For some reason, it seems whenever I put one stick of memory into the B1, B2, C1, and C2 slots, I get error 16, but it's not consistent. I had 2 sticks of memory in the A2 and B2 slots and it booted. Up fine, only recognizing the B2 slot of memory for some reason, and then I tried rebooting again and error 16. It's all over the place and ASRock tech support is of no help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).